# login failure on Ubuntu 12.03 when user exists and correct password entered

Tags: authentication, ubuntu-12.04, login

I manage an IT lab for students.I am experiencing this weird problem on some of our computers in the lab that i can login on some of the computers and can't login on some of the computers. These computers are like dumb terminals while file server that hosts user accounts is on another machine. Essentially each of these dumb computers mount the home directory from the file server. I have checked that each computer mounts the home directory properly (at least i see the correct entry for home directory on /etc/fstab file) but for some reason, there is authentication failure on some of the computers and it works on some of the computers.

Any idea what might be wrong on some of the lab computers or how to debug this.

I got a hint that /etc/passwd file on the file server should match with the local /etc/passwd file. It means these 2 files should be in sync.I think that is the solution.

Now the problem is Cronjobs are not successful. I mean some computers are updating and some are failing to update from the file server cronjob. Any idea how to debug this behavior where update happens on some computer and it does not happen on some.

Comment: Which machine is doing the authentication, the terminals or the server? Please try to describe the environment as clearly as possible.

Comment: The authentication is done by the terminal but It turns out that server is running cron job to push /etc/passwd file to the terminals every 5 minutes.

Comment: Are the cron jobs successful? Do the /etc/passwd files match on all computers?

Comment: @D34DM347 Cronjobs are not successful. I mean some computers are updating and some are failing to update from the cronjob. Any idea how to debug this behavior where update happens on some computer and it does not happen on some. Thanks

Comment: What error message does the cron job generate?

Answer (score 0):

So the reason was ssh keys for the machines which were re-imaged (reinstalled with Fresh Ubuntu Image) had to be put in to the server.